# Advanced Probability Problem

Tags: measure-theory

I have a problem as show below.
Let $(\Omega,F_j), j=1,2,\cdots$，be measurable space such that $F_j\subset F_{j+1}$ ,$j=1,2,\cdots$. Is $\bigcup_j F_j$ a $\sigma$ field? Why?

Comment: ur thoguhts m8?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_1,A_2,...$ are disjoint (non-empty) sets then you can explicitly write down $\mathbb F_n=\sigma(A_1,A_2,...,A_n)$. it consists of all possible unions of the sets  $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ and $(A_1\cup A_2\cup ...\cup A_n)^{c}$. You can easily see that the infinite union $A_1\cup A_2\cup ...$ does not belong to any one of these sigma algebras. Hence the union of these sigma algebras is not a sigma algebra.

Comment: I don't understand how conclusions about your 'sparse' definition of $\mathbb F_n$ can be extended to the given $F_n$, which may contain much more elements.

Comment: @Ingix I have given an example to show that union of an increasing family of sigma algebras need not be a sigma algebra.

Comment: Oh, I see. I assumed it was a proof that it doesn't work for *any* such sequence (assuming $\subset$ means proper subset).